# how do you add an image to a jquery tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I haven't seen this exact question addressed...if it has been, just please point me to it.

I'm using jquery's ui tooltip. I have one link that when you mouseover it, I'd like to show an image. Nothing has worked for me so far.

ui code in header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
(see <a id='riverroad' href='#' title='' >image of 1 Maple St.</a>)
```

code:

```
$( "#riverroad" ).tooltip({ content: "<img src='./images/myimage.jpg/>" });
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You didn't end the quote of the `src` tag : `"<img src='./images/myimage.jpg' />"`

Comment: after putting closing quote, did it work?

Comment: No, it still didn't. $( "#riverroad" ).tooltip({ content: "<img src='./images/myimage.jpg' />" });

Comment: I think you are missing to pass function(){...} to 'content' and also you should 'return' the image html, which you are not doing. Please refer to sample code:                      $("#btnRedirectToAbout").tooltip({ content: function () { return '<img src="../../Images/orderedList3.png" />'; } });

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this one :

**Html**

```
<a id="riverroad" href="#" title="" >image of 1 Maple St.</a>
```

**JQuery**

```
$( "#riverroad" ).tooltip({ content: '<img src="yourImagePath" />' });
```

See the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/vvVwD/).

Jquery 1.9.1 and JqueryUI 1.9.2 are included of course. Check if your image path is correct by the way.

Edit :
You told me that you're setting the link with jQuery, see this second working example :

**Html**

```
<div id="content">    
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#content").html('<a id="riverroad" href="#" title="" >image of 1 Maple St.</a>');
   $("#content #riverroad").tooltip({ content: '<img src="http://icdn.pro/images/fr/a/v/avatar-barbe-brun-homme-utilisateur-icone-9665-128.png" />' }); 

});
```

Here is the new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/vvVwD/1/) !

Comment: Still nothing, but where do I put this code? With $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
     
    });
  }); or with $(document).ready(function()?

Comment: Both should work, on the fiddle I used onLoad.If you watch the source code on the [jQueryUI API](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) website, they're doing it within a `$(function(){})`. Do you have some errors in your JS console ? Is the image path correct ?

Comment: I see this does work, actually! But I left out an element of my problem. My link is within $('#chart').html( "<a id='riverroad' href='#' title='' >image of 1 Maple St.</a>");

Comment: Woo hoo! Now the image is appearing on mouseover! One question, though. The image is now larger than the tooltip. How do I make the tooltip bigger than the image, please?

Comment: Just remove the `max-width: 300px;` from `.ui-tooltip` class in the `jquery-ui.css` ;) see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/vvVwD/2/)

Comment: I had trouble implementing this. Turns out you must have a title="" attribute for this to work

Comment: I don't understand. We're talking about jQuery here, nothing to do with MVC.

Answer (score 8):

First, you are missing the closing quote of your `src` tag. Your code should be :

```
$( "#riverroad" ).tooltip({ content: "<img src='./images/myimage.jpg' />" });
```

Moreover, this should be working with the following code as shown on [jQueryUI's website](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content) :

HTML :

```
<a id='riverroad' href='#' title='' >image of 1 Maple St.</a>
```

JS :

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
      items: "a",
      content: function() {
        var element = $( this );
        if (element.attr('id') === 'riverroad') {
          return "<img class='map' src='./images/myimage.jpg' />";
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here is a demo on jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QgPEw/1/

Comment: I've corrected my code that had a wrong condition. This should work better now as shown in the jsFiddle

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the HTML content directly in *title* and you'll be fine.

```
<a id="riverroad" href="#" title="<img src='http://icdn.pro/images/fr/a/v/avatar-barbe-brun-homme-utilisateur-icone-9665-128.png'" >image of 1 Maple St.</a>
```

Just remember to use single quotes inside *title*.

Comment: best answer i guess. clean and clear