# How do I add an image inside a jQuery UI tooltip?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I want to have a tooltip display an image. I tried the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274123/how-do-you-add-an-image-to-a-jquery-tooltip/15274658), but nothing worked. I've also tried other jQuery UI widgets, and they do work. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<a id='gamercard' href='https://live.xbox.com/en-US/Profile?Gamertag=Daddy+Kiefer' title=''>Daddy Kiefer</a>.</p>
```

js:

```
$(function () {

   $("#gamercard").tooltip({
       content: '<img src="http://gamercard.zaamit.com/nxe/Daddy%20Kiefer.png" />'
   });
});
```

Any advice on where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me with exact same code above:

http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/wu23h/show/

```
$(function () {

   $("#gamercard").tooltip({
       content: '<img src="http://gamercard.zaamit.com/nxe/Daddy%20Kiefer.png" />'
   });
});
```

Comment: After a little more inspection, I realized my jquery ui file was out of order. It works now, thanks!