# how to add tooltip image to more than one buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

how to add tooltip image to more than one buttons. i would like to create images that appear on mouse over the buttons, each button have separate images to popup.

I placing the buttons below; on hover they popup a image over it.

```
<div><a href="#">button 1</a></div>
<div><a href="#">button 2</a></div>
<div><a href="#">button 3</a></div>
```

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274123/how-do-you-add-an-image-to-a-jquery-tooltip?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Please check http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/vvVwD/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add different [jquery tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) image to the different button. In that case you need to mention which image you want to add in which button. I have added image url to `data-image` attribute for each button. Finally you need to call `tooltip` function for each button.

Don't forget to add `title` attribute to `a` tag.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <a href="#" data-image="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/" title="">button 1</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" data-image="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/" title="">button 2</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" data-image="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people/" title="">button 3</a>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
$('div a').each(function(){
    var imageUrl = $(this).data('image');
    $(this).tooltip({ content: '<img src="'+ imageUrl +'" />' });
});
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/vvVwD/1234/)

You can also call `tooltip` function following way-

```
$( document ).tooltip({
    items: "div a",
    content: function() {
        return '<img  src="'+ $(this).data('image') +'" />';
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/vvVwD/1235/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JqueryUI tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) to create *Customizable, themeable* tooltips.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Raghu9972/4Lydsw1o/) that has 3 buttons and a random image will popup when hovered on it.

HTML:

```
<a id="id1" href="#" title="">button 1</a>
<a id="id2" href="#" title="">button 2</a>
<a id="id3" href="#" title="">button 3</a>
```

Javascript with JqueryUI:

```
$( "#id1" ).tooltip({ content: '<img src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=1" />' });
$( "#id2" ).tooltip({ content: '<img src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=2" />' });
$( "#id3" ).tooltip({ content: '<img src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=3" />' });
```

I'm not sure whether this is what you're looking for?!