# How to add image in the title of the Tool Tip?

Tags: html

I want to add image in the title of the button along with text.. 
I have already tried to add  image through using following php code in title="".

```
 <?php  echo"<img class='file-attach'     src='".get_template_directory_uri()."/images/file-attachment.png'/>"; ?>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default tooltip-buttons" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Here you'll see">?</button>
```

Comment: Using the native `title` attribute provided, no you cannot do that. You will have to implement a custom one if you need one that supports pictures as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274123/how-do-you-add-an-image-to-a-jquery-tooltip

Comment: Refer to this link might solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274123/how-do-you-add-an-image-to-a-jquery-tooltip

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a tooltip with picture that resembles the real ones, and here is the code:

```
$("[ctitle]").hover(
  function(e) {
    $("<div id='txt'>").css({
      "display": "none",
      "width": "auto",
      "height": "auto",
      "color": "#767676",
      "border": "solid 1px #767676",
      "font-size": "12px",
      "font-family": "Arial",
      "position": "absolute",
      "padding": "2px 3px 2px 3px",
      "background-color": "white",
      "box-shadow": "3px 3px 1px gray",
      "left": 0,
      "top": 0
    }).appendTo("body").html($(this).attr('ctitle')).stop().fadeToggle().css({
      "top": e.pageY,
      "left": e.pageX
    });

  },
  function() {
    $("[id='txt']").stop().fadeToggle(function(){
            $(this).remove();
        })
  }
);
```

Basically add the code to your page (include JQuery) and use `ctitle` instead of `title`. In the `ctitle` attribute you can add other HTML codes to format.

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8e21bzx7/)