# How can I show an image when hover in a link?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to show a hidden section when hover in a link, but I can't make it.

```html
<section class="projects">
    <section id="project-list">
        <p id="america-regular-list"><a id="fromdesigner" href="">From Designer to Designer</a></p>
        <p id="america-regular-list"><a href="">Wasted Time</a></p>
        <p id="america-regular-list"><a href="">Thirty Logos</a></p>
        <p id="america-regular-list"><a href="">Aesthetic Posters</a></p>
    </section>
</section>
<section class="preview">
    <section id="preview-01"><img src="img/preview-project-01.jpg"/></section>
</section>
```

I want to show #preview-01 when hover #fromdesigner and replicate to the other links and images.

[This is how website looks without hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3MFe.jpg)

[And this is what I'm trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY6Yw.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I am creating my portfolio using HTML and CSS. In the home I have a list of links that lead to my projects and I would like to make hover on one of these links to show a cover image. The links and the images that correspond to them are in different sections.
I have tried several things and I do not get the desired effect.

Comment: Ok, so if i understand you correctly, you want a popup on mouseover which locates at the mouse, and shows the cover of that project as an image?

Comment: Yes, I added two images to clarify my question.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56425667/how-to-show-an-image-in-tooltip

Comment: Something like that?

Comment: he uses an awkward image(for its size) as example but i think you can work it out with this right?

Comment: Yes, I think it would work. But with a code like that can I place the image wherever I want? Or it has to be under the link?

Comment: First and foremost thing, please don't repeat the `id`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've a solution for you. I've posted it here. Hope it will be helpful.

```js
function imgShow1() {
  document.getElementById('preview-01-img').style.opacity = 1;
}

function imgHide1() {
  document.getElementById('preview-01-img').style.opacity = 0;
}

function imgShow2() {
  document.getElementById('preview-02-img').style.opacity = 1;
}

function imgHide2() {
  document.getElementById('preview-02-img').style.opacity = 0;
}

function imgShow3() {
  document.getElementById('preview-03-img').style.opacity = 1;
}

function imgHide3() {
  document.getElementById('preview-03-img').style.opacity = 0;
}

function imgShow4() {
  document.getElementById('preview-04-img').style.opacity = 1;
}

function imgHide4() {
  document.getElementById('preview-04-img').style.opacity = 0;
}
```

```css
.preview img {
  height: 10vw;
  width: 20vw;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .33s ease-in-out;
}

.preview section {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="projects">
    <section id="project-list">
        <p id="america-regular-list"><a id="fromdesigner" href="" onmouseover="imgShow1()" onmouseleave="imgHide1()">From Designer to Designer</a></p>
        <p id="america-regular-list"><a href="" onmouseover="imgShow2()" onmouseleave="imgHide2()">Wasted Time</a></p>
        <p id="america-regular-list"><a href="" onmouseover="imgShow3()" onmouseleave="imgHide3()">Thirty Logos</a></p>
        <p id="america-regular-list"><a href="" onmouseover="imgShow4()" onmouseleave="imgHide4()">Aesthetic Posters</a></p>
    </section>
</section>
<section class="preview">
    <section id="preview-01"><img id="preview-01-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/J67Ukc8.jpg"/>
    <section id="preview-02"><img id="preview-02-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/J67Ukc8.jpg"/>
    <section id="preview-03"><img id="preview-03-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/J67Ukc8.jpg"/>
    <section id="preview-04"><img id="preview-04-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/J67Ukc8.jpg"/></section>
</section>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, but now how can I make the second link show another image?

Comment: @LuisoVázquez I've edited my solution according to your requirement. Check it. And one more thing, if it works for you then please mark the answer as accepted. :)

Comment: Works perfect! Just what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome @LuisoVázquez . Happy to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in css you cant do hover effect unless if you target child or sibling, i have edit your html to be like the next snippet, its not the best solution, and not responsive, but at least without javascript

```css
#projects{
  position: relative;
}

p{
  width: 50%;
}
.preview{
  display: none;
}
img{
  width: 50%;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px
}
#america-regular-list1:hover ~ .preview{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="projects">
    <section id="project-list">
        <p id="america-regular-list1"><a id="fromdesigner" href="">From Designer to Designer</a></p>
        <p id="america-regular-list"><a href="">Wasted Time</a></p>
        <p id="america-regular-list"><a href="">Thirty Logos</a></p>
        <p id="america-regular-list"><a href="">Aesthetic Posters</a></p>
      
      <div class="preview"><img src="https://www.jamierubin.net/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Blog-Header-Burke.jpg"/></div>
    </section>
</section>
```

you can achieve what u want easily in jQuery or vanila JS.

**my note : don't repeat ID in your html, its not good practice.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your problem here. But you could embed each image under each link.

```
    <section id="project-list">
        <p id="america-regular-list"><a id="fromdesigner" href="">From Designer to Designer</a><img src="img/preview-project-01.jpg" id="hello"/></p>
        <p id="america-regular-list"><a href="">Wasted Time</a><img src="img/preview-project-01.jpg" /></p>
        <p id="america-regular-list"><a href="">Thirty Logos</a><img src="img/preview-project-01.jpg"/></p>
        <p id="america-regular-list"><a href="">Aesthetic Posters</a><img src="img/preview-project-01.jpg"/></p>
    </section>
</section>
```

In Css:

```
img{
display: none;
}
a#fromdesigner:hover #hello{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope it helps!!